# How to create editable text with effects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, text, illustrator-effects

I need help to know by steps how to create the same as the attached snapshot. It's done in Adobe Illustrator (Strokes, fills and effects from the appearance box), I manage to create editable transparent text with the 2 white strokes inside and outside the text.
What I couldn't do is how to create the white depth (the white depth with scratches) and avoiding to show the depth inside or behind the transparent text

[image: The steps how to create this image]

Comment: Just to clarify, that image is what you're trying to achieve, right? If so, can you upload an image of your attempt so far?

Comment: Hi John,

Please have a look on the link below and let me know if the editable text can be created or not. Many thanks

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDa_ZWpN150

Answer (score 1):

I can't help but wonder why you don't just examine the Appearance panel to see the effect there. But then, perhaps you only have the screenshot and not the actual Illustrator file.

The only way I can think to do this would be via **blending modes**. If you fill the interior of the type with black, then set the blending mode to `Screen`, the black will disappear on a dark background leaving the white strokes and block shadow visible.

Without blending modes, I don't believe there's any way to get the transparent interior unless the font is designed with a transparent interior. However, if the font comes with a transparent interior, the inline stroke becomes problematic to create.

[image]

<sub>Right-click/Control-click and choose `Open image in new tab/window` to see it larger.</sub>

Comment: Hi Scott!

Thanks for your answer ... Please do open the link below so you would know from where I took the snapshot, I downloaded the same font the tutor using in the video

Many thanks!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDa_ZWpN150

Comment: The video doesn't' explain how he got the appearance.. it's a waste of time to watch it.  What I've posted above should work.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this with text that can be editable as a text object. You'll have to outline it.

- Create your type. Kern it, track it, whatever. Outline it.
- Create a copy, paste it in back, move it down to create the shadow.
- Blend the two to create the 3D shadow effect.
- Create another copy of the original outlines, paste in front,
  subtract from 3D shadow compound shape. Fill this shape with white,
  add grunge.
- Create another copy, paste in front. Trans fill, white stroke.

Alternatively, there are some fonts that are built like this. If you can find one that suits your needs, then you'll have editable text.